Is my use case diagram about AI expertizer interpretable?
I have this Use-case diagram:

Stop Scroll Here!!!
What is your first impression about the use case? I mean is it interpretable intuitively? After you answer it, I will explain what that use case is talking about.
Explanation (Spoiler Alert)
Based on SRS description:
The Fetal Expertizer is an advanced system designed to assist healthcare professionals in detecting fetal abnormalities through image analysis, primarily using ultrasound data. Powered by deep learning algorithms, it provides real-time insights into potential issues, improving diagnostic accuracy and ultimately enhancing patient outcomes.
The system will be built on Amazon Web Services (AWS) to leverage its scalability, reliability, and security. Key services in the tech stack will include AWS Fargate for containerized microservices, ensuring the system is highly available and can scale efficiently. For backend data storage, the system will use Amazon DynamoDB, a fully managed NoSQL database, to store common application data, enabling fast and flexible access to data across different parts of the system. Other services include Amazon S3 for data storage, Amazon SageMaker for model training and evaluation, and AWS Lambda for serverless computing. These services will work together to ensure smooth performance, scalability, and flexibility as the system evolves.
A distinctive feature of the Fetal Expertizer is its role-based operational model, which defines clear responsibilities for various actors: Acquisitors collect the data, Annotators label the data, Validators verify both collected and labeled data, Trainers improve the models, Evaluators assess model performance, and Administrators manage system configurations and user roles. The Model Consumer role is flexible, encompassing both healthcare professionals who use the system for diagnostic insights and patients who can access their own reports. This approach ensures that the system is tailored to the needs of various stakeholders, driving continuous improvement and making it adaptable to real-world clinical workflows.
Question
Is my use-case correct? Mainly about how I use extend and include keyword. Additionaly about its interpretability.

Sorry if this is not the answer you expect, but no, this use-case is incorrect:

It misuses «include» to emulate sequences of steps.  This is not the purpose of a use case diagram, and results in strange interpretations , such as,  by transitive closure of the inclusion, that Upload image for training purpose would include Train model and even the use of the deployed model by its consumers.  This seems misleading, as use of the deployed model is independent of the upload of training material.

It may misuse «extend» to emulate user interface design or again workflow dependencies.  But it could also be a legitimate use.


I recommend to revisit the diagram, simplifying it by focusing only on higher level goals, e.g. train model, and analyse image with the model.
In a second step consider activity diagrams to model the sequence of actions for a use case, e.g. for training the model:  upload-> labelling-> (optional quality assessment -> training -> deployment
If you want some more details in the Use case diagram, you could be tempted to use functional decomposition, by showing that training includes capturing images, labelling them etc. But functional decomposition is not recommended, as it leads to complex diagrams that nobody understands anymore except the modeler.

So, to summary. I just need the associative arrow only, since I misused include and extend as sequence diagram?

@MuhammadIkhwanPerwira: you don't need a use case diagram for describing this level of detail at all. Excluding the administrative part (for which a UCD does not bring much value), an activity diagram would probably suit you better. The different steps/activities in your system have a clear ordering, that's best expressed with control flow arrows, not associative arrows.

@DocBrown but, how about overview section in my SRS doc? Does it mean the overview section part should be filled with activity diagram instead of use case diagram?

@MuhammadIkhwanPerwira: honestly, for someone who knows only your post and neither your SRS doc nor your audience this is not answerable. Maybe a use case diagram at a higher level of abstraction will be fine, or maybe you don't need one - that is a decision you have to make by yourself. I can only tell you for the processes or tasks in this post an activity diagram would be the better tool.

I see, actually that's the reason why I asked this question, to verify whether my highest level abstraction of use case is intepretable or not for the overview section in my SRS doc.

If I look at the typical table of content of an SRS in ISO 29148:2018,  The overview  use case I suggested would be used in the introductory part,  showing the main purpose and introducing the different kind of users of the software.  Then, an SRS is primarily based on product functions.  Here you have the choice for each of the "Kite level" (summary) use cases you could introduce a separate, focused use case diagram showing goals at "see level" (user goal), although I'd really go for an activity diagram, each action a function.

In an SRS I'd recommend to avoid the "fish level" (sub function), because this level of detail implies a big up-front design. If contractually required to go at this level, prefer a tabular view or an activity diagram. If given some more  flexibility, specify this level only via "use case slices" (see Use case 2.0) or "stories"

My first impression is that you don't really understand what a use-case diagram shows.
A use-case diagram doesn't show how a single use-case works. It can best be regarded as a graphical table-of-contents for the use-cases that exist within the system and the principle actors that interact with the system.

I see, "a graphical table-of-contents", like a detail explanation of acquisitor actor who upload the image that needs several step like login, modify metadata, delete uploaded image, and so on. Thus, it's just one use case for acquisitor who uploaded image.  And I need to create separate system boundary for another role like annotator in which it depends on availability of uploaded image from acquisitor.

@MuhammadIkhwanPerwira, you are still thinking in too much detail. A use-case diagram just gives a high level overview of why the actors want to use the system. Nothing more.
